# Limit file size in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The [official documentation for FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) says:

> -fs limit_size (output)
>
> Set the file size limit, expressed in bytes. No further chunk of bytes is written after the limit is exceeded. The size of the output file is slightly more than the requested file size.

This is very confusing. If the file size is slightly more than the requested file size then I have the following questions:

1. What determines how much more (than the requested file size) the file will consume?
2. How much more will the file exceed the requested file size?
3. Is there any way to set the file size exactly?
4. What is the point of having the `-fs` if it does not actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What determines how much more (than the requested file size) the file will consume?*

The size of the trailer, if any, written by the output file muxer. Sizes of any packets already sent to the muxer, but not yet flushed to disk. The first can't be known beforehand; the second may be possible in theory but not straightforward.

*How much more will the file exceed the requested file size?*

See above.

*Is there any way to set the file size exactly?*

No. Transcoding in ffmpeg is a multi-layered process. `-fs` acts at a relatively high level, and there are dozens of output muxers in ffmpeg, each with their own overhead.  So `fs` is not strictly enforceable in principle, while still generating a valid file.

*What is the point of having the -fs if it does not actually work?*

It was added in 2005 and has hardly been changed since. Its implementation could be improved somewhat but not made perfect due to how media files are constructed. The reason I suspect that improvements have rarely been attempted is that there are very few valid use cases for it - maybe to avoid breaching account / filesystem quotas - so the utility to effort ratio is low.

What most users want is to have a complete transcoding operation with a target file size in mind. For that, setting encoder bitrate is the correct method. `-fs` is not meant for that purpose.